# How do I figure out the position of where a regex ends?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, position

Using Ruby 2.4.  If I want to find out the position of a where a regex occurs in a string, I can do

```
2.4.0 :014 > line = "1 a b     c d"
 => "1 a b     c d" 
2.4.0 :015 > string_tokens = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
 => ["a", "b", "c", "d"] 

2.4.0 :025 > first_pos = line.index( /#{string_tokens.join(" ").gsub(" ", "\s+")}/ )
 => 7
```

but how would I determine the position of where the regex ends in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
line = "1 a b     c d"
string_tokens = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

I believe the OP intended to form the regular expression as follows.

```
r = /#{string_tokens.join('\s+')}/
  #=> /a\s+b\s+c\s+d/
```

Then

```
line =~ r
  #=> 2
```

tells us there is a match beginning at offset `2` of `line`. To find where the match ends we can use either of the following methods.

**First way**

```
(line =~ r) + line[r].size - 1
  #=> 12
```

as

```
line[r]
  #=> "a b     c d"
```

**Second way**

This uses [Regexp::last_match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match) and [MachData#end](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/MatchData.html#method-i-end).

```
line =~ r
  #=> 2

Regexp.last_match.end(0)-1
  #=> 12
```

`LastMatchend(n)` returns "the offset of the character immediately following the end of the nth element of the match array in the string". Hence, the need for `-1`.